# slick slider create unexpected row

Tags: javascript, html, css, frontend

I want to create a slick slider on my website. it should have just one row but with any values for slides to show and slides to scroll, it creates an unwanted row. here is the code:

it is like this:

I have a list like : 1, 2, 3, 4, 5

it should be shown like this: 1,2,3,4,5

but it is shown like this:

1,2,3,4

5

```
<div class="related-container mt-1">
    {% for product in popular_products %}
        <div class="related-item" {% if product.show_main_price != '0' %} style='border: #24841599 3px solid;' {% endif %} >
            <a href="{{ product.page_url }}">
                <img class="related-item-image" src="{{ product.list_image_url }}" alt="{{ product.title }}"/>
                <div class="related-info">
                    <div class="text-lg title">
                        {{ product.title }}
                        {% if product.show_main_price != '0' %}
                        <div style="text-decoration: line-through; text-decoration-color: red;color: red; margin-top: 10px">{{ product.show_main_price }}</div>
                        {% endif %}  
                    </div>
                    {% with product.main_field_val as main_field_val %}
                        {% if main_field_val.image_url %}
                            <img class="main-field-image" src="{{ main_field_val.image_url }}"
                                 title="{{ main_field_val.title }}" alt="{{ main_field_val.title }}"/>
                        {% else %}
                            <div class="main-field-image">{{ main_field_val.title }}</div>
                        {% endif %}
                    {% endwith %}
                </div>
            </a>
            {% if product.can_add_to_cart %}
                <button type="button" class="related-btn pull-left active"
                        onclick="addToCartBtn('{{ product.add_cart_url }}')">
                    <span class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></span> {{ product.show_price }}
                </button>
            {% else %}
                <button type="button" class="related-btn pull-left">
                    ###
                </button>
            {% endif %}
        </div>
    {% endfor %}
</div>
```

And for **JS** it has:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

$('.related-container').slick({
    infinite: false,
    slidesToShow: 4,
    slidesToScroll: 2,
    rtl: true,
    prevArrow: '<div class="right-arrow"></div>',
    nextArrow: '<div class="left-arrow"></div>',
    adaptiveHeight: true,
    responsive: [
        {
            breakpoint: 900,
            settings: {
                slidesToShow: 1.3,
                slidesToScroll: 1
            }
        }
    ]
});
```

`related_products` is a list of query set. 
this code leads to a slick slider and it shows all items in `related_products` properly but every time with any length of `related_products`, last item in slider jump in a new row. so it creates an unwanted row in the slider.

Answer (score 0):

Try giving fixed height (if OK) and overflow-x:scroll for related-container.

Comment: fixed heights are not usable in this case. the main question is how is it possible to make a new row while I'm not allowing it.
P.S: X:scroll is already overflowed and it is scrollable in X-axis.